# Creating interface for concrete class with enum C#?

Tags: c#, interface, dependency-injection, enums, separation-of-concerns

Pardon any mistakes, this is one of my first questions. I would really appreciate some guidance here. I tried searching for previous questions, but I couldn't quite word the question correctly.

I'm trying to create a simple Logger with an interface class, but I want to have the interface and the Logger class in separate projects within the solution. I'm trying to separate all my interfaces from the concrete implementations.

However, the Logger class I've created contains an enum:

```
public class Logger : ILogger 
{
    public enum LogSeverity
    {
        None = 0,
        Verbose = 1, 
        Information = 2,
        Warning = 3,
        Error = 4,
        Critical = 5
    }

    public void Log(string message)
    { ... }

    public void Log(string message, LogSeverity severity)
    { ... }
}
```

Then I have an interface (in a separate project) for ILogger:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string message);

    void Log(string message, LogSeverity severity);
}
```

I'm running into issues with this as the interface does not know about the LogSeverity enum, and I run into circular dependency issues if I try to wire the two separate projects together.

Could anyone possibly give me some insight on how to manage enums while utilizing an interface? It's probably something very simple I'm missing. Sorry if the question is so vague. This all comes about as I'm trying to implement dependency injection while separating my interfaces into their own project.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your Enum is part of a public API (as guaranteed by your interface), then you should put the Enum in that project as well.  Also, to the downvoter, this question is well formed and shows effort to understand the problem.  You should retract your downvote.

Comment: Why oh why do people keep implementing loggers?! https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your enum `LogSeverity` describes a contract, so if you want it separated into two assemblies, add interface and enum to one assembly and implementation to a different assembly.

Interfaces assembly:

```
public enum LogSeverity
{
    // enum items
}

public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string message);

    void Log(string message, LogSeverity severity);
}
```

Implementation assembly:

```
public class Logger : ILogger 
{

    public void Log(string message)
    { ... }

    public void Log(string message, LogSeverity severity)
    { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! You folks just saved me a lot of time! I was trying to include the enum within the interface scope and it was telling me that an interface can't contain an enum. I knew it was something simple I was missing. You guys/gals are the best!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to put the `Enum` in the project with the interface.

The idea of separating your interface into a separate project is so it can be re-used in different projects to create different `ILogger` implementations that can be injected as desired. If `ILogger` references `LogSeverity` then potential implementors of this interface would need access to it - so putting it in a project with another concrete implementation of the interface doesn't really make sense

Comment: Thanks kindly for the reply! I would upvote you, but I'm too low on the totem pole :)

Comment: No worries - I'll give you a +1 to get you on your way.